# Finding dimension of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 3 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 5 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $V$ be the vector space of all $X\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $AX=0$. Then $\dim(V)$ is:
>
> **a)** $0$
> **b)** $1$
> **c)** $2$
> **d)** $3$
>
> **Solution: b)**

Comment: As rank of vector matrix is 2. Implies we need 2 linear independent vectors to make this vector space.i.e its basis must have 2 elements => its dimension must be 2 'i guess'

Comment: Nop. The rank of the matrix = dimension of its image or, if you prefer, the dimension of its column space (it is the same, of course), so using the dimensions' theorem (or what ammounts to the same: the rank-nullity theorem), its kernel has dimension...?

Comment: I edited the content of the image into your question. Please check if I have done so correctly. At the moment, your question is lacking context. Could you please add into your question your thoughts on the problem, and what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

$V$ is the null-space of $A$. Now, because $A$ has $3$ columns, by the Rank-Nullity Theorem, $$dim(V) + Rank(A) = 3$$ 
On writing $A$ is RRE-form you will get  $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -4 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
Hence $Rank(A) = 2$ and therefore $dim(V)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Dimension of the vector space = Nullity $A$

As Rank $A=2$, hence Nullity $A=1$.